# Matrix operations in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I want to write a function so that it takes a Matrix, a row number and a column number. And thereafter to get the matrix such that 1 in the A(i,j) position and zeros in all the other positions in the i-th column using only row operations. 
I am new to Python. Please give me some help. Thank you.

How I started is as this,

`import numpy as np`

`def A = np.array([B])` # the matrix B is yet to provide

`def i = A[i,:]`

`def j= A[:,j]`

But this doesn't seems to be working!

Comment: Why do you need an input matrix to get rid of it and just put a 1 and zeros, only for the size ?

Comment: @azro, i think the original post before you edit really showed a lot of the issues, please consider reverting it.

Comment: Not very clear. Are you trying to do a pivot operation (as in Gauss-Jordan)? If so, your code doesn't seem to be very related to the problem. I'm not sure why you would expect it to work. Make sure that you understand the algorithm that you are trying to implement before you write code.

Comment: `def` defines a function in Python, not a variable. I'd start with a basic Python tutorial before working on this specific problem

Answer (score 1):

`

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1],[2, 2, 2, 2],[3, 3, 3, 3]])


def func(matrix, col, row):
    matrix[:, col] = 0
    matrix[row, col] = 1


func(m, 1, 1)

print(m)`
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
import numpy as np          
from functools import reduce

N = 6
A = np.random.randint(0,10,(N,N))
i,j = np.random.randint(0,N,2)
A
# array([[8, 9, 8, 1, 9, 4],
#        [0, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2],
#        [2, 7, 4, 6, 2, 7],
#        [9, 8, 1, 5, 1, 9],
#        [0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 3],
#        [3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7]])
i,j
# (5, 1)
```

Helpers:

```
I = np.identity(N)                    
e = I[:,None]      # standard base row vectors                   
eT = I[...,None]   # standard base column vectors
```

The row ops:

```
rowops = [I + eT[i]@e[i]*(1/A[i,j]-1)] + [I - (eT[k]*A[k,j])@(e[i]/A[i,j]) for k in range(6) if k!=i]
```

The first one scales the ith row. The others subtract the ith row times a factor from the kth row.

Let's apply them one by one and keep track of the jth column:

```
B = A.copy()                       
for r in reversed(rowops):
    print(B[:,j])
    B = r@B
# [9 3 7 8 1 4]
# [9. 3. 7. 8. 0. 4.]
# [9. 3. 7. 0. 0. 4.]
# [9. 3. 0. 0. 0. 4.]
# [9. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4.]
print(B[:,j])
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
```

Now let's combine all rowops into a single op by multiplying them:

```
combined = reduce(np.matmul,rowops)
```

This gives indeed the same result when applied to `A`

```
np.allclose(combined@A,B)
# True
```

This combined op we could have obtained directly:

```
R = I + (eT[i]-A@eT[j])@e[i]/A[i,j]
```

Check:

```
np.allclose(combined,R)
# True
```

Applied to A:

```
R@A
# array([[  1.25,   0.  ,  -3.25,   1.  ,  -4.5 , -11.75],
#        [ -2.25,   0.  ,   1.25,   4.  ,   0.5 ,  -3.25],
#        [ -3.25,   0.  ,  -4.75,   6.  ,  -8.5 ,  -5.25],
#        [  3.  ,   0.  ,  -9.  ,   5.  , -11.  ,  -5.  ],
#        [ -0.75,   0.  ,  -1.25,   8.  ,  -1.5 ,   1.25],
#        [  0.75,   1.  ,   1.25,   0.  ,   1.5 ,   1.75]])
```